# Flutter dropdown items not showing

Tags: flutter, dart

I am showing i simple drop down but my options are not opening mean its not showing a dropdown.

I have a simple list like this

```
[352094083791878, 358480083322091, 358480081409924]
```

This is my code

```
class _SettingPageState extends State<SettingPage> {
  bool isSwitched = false;

  bool _shoW = true;
  var items = [];
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    getImi();
  }

  getImi() async {
    final storage = new FlutterSecureStorage();

    String userNumber = await storage.read(key: "userNumber");
    String userPassword = await storage.read(key: "userPassword");

    print('showimi');
    print(userNumber);
    print(userPassword);

    var map = new Map<String, dynamic>();

    showDialog(
        context: context,
        barrierDismissible: false,
        builder: (BuildContext context) {
          return Center(
              child: SpinKitWave(
                  color: Color(0xff00abb5), type: SpinKitWaveType.center));
        });

    var url =
        'http://api.igiinsurance.com.pk:8888/drive_api/login.php?number=${userNumber}&password=${userPassword}';
    print(url);
    http.Response res = await http.get(
      url,
      headers: <String, String>{'token': 'c66026133e80d4960f0a5b7d418a4d08'},
    );
    var data = json.decode(res.body.toString());
    print(data);

    if (data['status'].toString() == "Success") {
      Navigator.pop(context);
      _shoW = true;

      data['data'].forEach((row) {
        print(row['imei_number']);
        items.add(row['imei_number']);

        print(items);
      });
    } else {
      Navigator.pop(context);
      _shoW = false;
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    double width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    double height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    return Scaffold(
      body: DecoratedBox(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          image: DecorationImage(
              image: AssetImage("images/sidebg.png"), fit: BoxFit.cover),
        ),
        child: Column(
          children: [
            _shoW
                ? DropdownButton(
                    hint: Text('Select Vechile'),
                    items: items.map((val) {
                      return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                        value: val,
                        child: new Text(val),
                      );
                    }).toList(),
                    onChanged: null)
                : Container()
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I am simply adding values in the Items array. I need to show the array in the select down list. But it's not opening the options i have try to put static list but that's also not working .

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `onChanged` to not `null` value. `onChanged` without listener cannot allow you to open list.

If you need to showing current selected value, pass `value` parameter to `DropdownButton`. Also you can find more examples in [Official Flutter Documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/DropdownButton-class.html).

Answer (score 0):

Change Your Code Like THis :

```
if (data['status'].toString() == "Success") {
          Navigator.pop(context);
    
    setState(){
          _shoW = true;
    }
    
    
          data['data'].forEach((row) {
            print(row['imei_number']);
            items.add(row['imei_number']);
    
            print(items);
          });
        } else {
          Navigator.pop(context);
    setState(){
          _shoW = false;
    }
    
         
        }
```